# VueJS and SASS - Import and use SASS variables in script

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I'm currently working on a VueJS project with a SASS integration, and I would like to get access to the SASS variables inside the script part of the component to make dynamic style calculations. I saw examples of this with pure JS, and I'm trying to translate that to a VueJS component.
So far, I've been able to integrate SASS variables in the *style* part of the Vue file, but I can't get the variables imported into the script of the component.

I tried the following:
Exporting the variables from my scss file:

```scss
:export {
    primaryColor: $primary;
}
```

And then import the file in my component:

```js
import variables from '@/assets/scss/main.scss'
```

And access it like so: `variables.primaryColor`

But I can't get it working, `variables` is always an empty object with no value inside. I'm using Nuxt with the packages `node-sass` and `sass-loader` installed. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just access the variables from a SASS file you can add this to `configureWebpack` in your `vue.config.js` file:

```js
module:{
  rules: [{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{
      loader: "style-loader"
    }, {
      loader: "css-loader" 
    }, {
      loader: "sass-loader"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Then let's say that you have a file containing your SASS variables called `style.sass` that looks something like this

```
$btn-color: #D75893

:export
    buttonColor: $btn-color
```

In your `<script>` tag you can import your SASS variables file like so

```js
import styleInfo from 'style.sass';
```

and access your variables like so

```js
console.log("The button color is", styleInfo.buttonColor);
```

*Note:* It is [not possible](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html) to dynamically change SASS variables at run time as the variables are compiled.

**Sources:** [This article from HashRocket](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript) and [This article from itnext](https://itnext.io/sharing-variables-between-js-and-sass-using-webpack-sass-loader-713f51fa7fa0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm using Nuxt so it adds a little more complexity, but I hope your answer gave me enough informations. 

Answer (score 1):

The config file changes did not work for me. Here is how I did it without touching any config file:

In your component , write the import using Vue-loader instead of the usual import syntax:

```
import variables from '@/assets/scss/main.scss?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&module=1'
```

This code includes: scss file path + queries which specifically ask Vue-loader to load CSS. The query starts after the `?`.

You can also import the css variables from the same component's `<style>` tag to `<script>`. To do this, in the component's `script` tag, change the scss file path to your component's path:

```
import variables from '@/MyComponentName.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&module=1'
```

Source: [How to share SASS variables with JavaScript code in VueJS](https://dev.to/pecus/how-to-share-sass-variables-with-javascript-code-in-vuejs-55p3)